# Is there any db2 image available which can be pulled in docker?

Tags: docker, docker-image

I want to know if there are any db2 images already present so that i can start a container from the image directly.

I went through the below link which says ibmcom/db2express-c is depricated.
https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2express-c/

Answer (score 0):

IBM have a new image. The link is in the old express-c image.
https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2